# Pandas: I need the row number based on the column and the value in that column

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet and I need to find which row a given value is stored based on the value itself and the column it is in.

Let's say the sheet looks like this:

```
    50   75
1   14  9,5
2  143   95
3  215  143
4  286  191
```

I want the code to tell me that the "286" in the "50" column is in the "4" row.

I've tried using df.index

`num_row = df[df['50'] == '286'].index`

But it only results in a KeyError caused by the "50".

Comment: the column might be `50` the number, not `"50"`. Do `print(df.columns)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process data as strings, don't let Pandas infer the `dtype` when you load your excel sheet with [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', dtype=str)
num_row = df[df['50'] == '286'].index
```

Output:

```
>>> num_row
Index([4], dtype='int64')
```